# Connecting PubNub to freeboard instance

Tags: pubnub, freeboard

I have installed freeboard on my own hosting and I'm unable to connect it to PubNub. 
I have tried using the mqtt plug-in to connect to pubnub through MQTT but it didn't work.. 
How can I connect PubNub to freeboard ? My own instance of freeboard not a dashboard hosted by freeboard.io

Comment: I was going to post an answer but the one posted below is much nicer +1

Answer (score 3):

I can give you some pointers. While [PubNub supports MQTT](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/mqtt-pubnub-bridge/getting-started?devrel_so=connecting-pubnub-to-freeboard-instance) it is not necessary to use the protocol. Depending on the IoT device you are using, you can use the standard PubNub connection with any of the SDKs for a language your device supports.

If you do want to use MQTT, you can use Python and Paho:

```python
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

publish_key = "<your publish key>"
subscribe_key = "<your subscribe key>"
client_id = "<your unique client identifier>"


client = mqtt.Client(client_id=publish_key + "/" + subscribe_key + "/" + client_id)
client.connect("mqtt.pndsn.com", 1883, 60)
client.publish("<topic to publish>", json.dumps({ "hi": 10 }))
```

What this code does is it publishes JSON data to an MQTT topic (channel in PubNub lingo).

Instead of "hi = 10" you can publish data that is suitable for your dashboard. I insist on including a Unix timestamp so you know when the data was submitted.

You can also use the [PubNub standard publish with Python](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/python/pubnub-python-sdk?devrel_so=connecting-pubnub-to-freeboard-instance) or any other language that there is an SDK for ([there's more than 70 SDKs](https://www.pubnub.com/docs?devrel_so=connecting-pubnub-to-freeboard-instance)).

```python
import time
from pubnub.pnconfiguration import PNConfiguration
from pubnub.pubnub import PubNub

pnconfig = PNConfiguration()
pnconfig.publish_key = '<your publish key>'
pubnub = PubNub(pnconfig)

## makes a timetoken that is easily converted to 
## a JavaScript date object in a web browser
javascript_timetoken = int(time.time() * 1000) 

pubnub.publish().channel("my_channel").message({
    'tt': javascript_timetoken,
    'foo': 'bar'
}).sync()
```

Now that this message has been published it can be received in realtime in your dashboard that is open in a web browser. If the dashboard is not open at the time a message is published, it can be retrieved later using [PubNub storage and playback](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/storage-and-history?devrel_so=connecting-pubnub-to-freeboard-instance).

[image]

You can enable message retention in the [PubNub Admin Dashboard](https://admin.pubnub.com/?devrel_so=connecting-pubnub-to-freeboard-instance) under the key info tab.

[image: pubnub history]

This is what the [JavaScript code](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk?devrel_so=connecting-pubnub-to-freeboard-instance) for subscribe would look like in the web page with the dashboard.

```js
<script src="https://cdn.pubnub.com/sdk/javascript/pubnub.4.20.2.js"></script>
<script>
var pubnub = new PubNub({
    subscribeKey: "mySubscribeKey",
    ssl: true
});

var time;

pubnub.addListener({
    message: function(message) {
        time = new Date(message.tt);
        // do more stuff
        // write data to the dashboard
    },
});

pubnub.subscribe({
    channels: ['my_channel'] 
});

// Get messages from the channel history in case there were 
// updates that happened while the browser was not yet opened
pubnub.history(
    {
        channel: 'my_channel',
        reverse: true, // Setting to true will traverse the time line in reverse starting with the oldest message first.
        count: 100, // how many items to fetch
        stringifiedTimeToken: true, // false is the default
        start: '123123123123', // start time token to fetch
        end: '123123123133' // end timetoken to fetch
    },
    function (status, response) {
        response.messages.forEach(function (message) {
            time = new Date(message.tt);
            // do more stuff
            // write data to the dashboard
        });
    }
);
```